# Swift. Error in working with UIApplication.shared

Tags: swiftui

This question, in the old program that is implemented under UIKit, was done like this.
Condition in which the following actions are performed:

```
if(theApp().m_Disp.Connecttosrv(self.SelCon)) {
```

In the condition, the function is accessed

```
func theApp() -> iSPultApp!
{
return UIApplication.shared as? iSPultApp
}
```

Where next the class is called from the function

```
class iSPultApp: UIApplication {
var m_Disp: Chroot = Chroot()
```

Everything works there, is it possible to redo it somehow for SwiftUI?
The program goes to func theApp (), and then instead of going to the class, returns to the condition and there is an error:

```
if(theApp().m_Disp.Connecttosrv(self.SelCon)) {
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.
```

self.SelCon is not empty, but filled with data. apparently, nil is passed in func theApp()

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Your code claims that `theApp()` can't return nil, which isn't true.  Try using the debugger to see what kind of thing `UIApplication.shared` really is.

Comment: I tried and it turns out that it seems to be not empty, then it is unclear why the error appears
screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/Qm6H-JnwFIWadg

Comment: Maybe it's a plain `UIApplication` object instead of the type you're trying to cast it to.  In that case `as?` would create nil.